# blank output after solving the captcha using pytesseract?

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am trying to solve a captcha :

[image: captcha image]

and run a script :

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract

path_to_tesseract = r"/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/5.0.1/bin/tesseract"
image_path2 = r"captcha2.jpg"
img = Image.open(image_path2)
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text[:-1])
captchaText=text[:-1]
```

but output is blank and when I use the same script with the following captcha:

[image: second captcha]

it works great.

Comment: #Captcha works.

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: Turn anything that isn't black to white and line up the letters...